# Why doesn't this svg path animate?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, svg-animate

I have a simple SVG with just one path in it and two `<animate>` elements that are supposed to change the `d` attribute with a 250ms transition and back. When the parent is clicked, the JavaScript triggers the animation. This works to change the `d` attribute, but there is no transition; it just happens immediately. Why doesn't it animate?

```js
var animationTo = document.getElementById("animation-to"),
  animationFrom = document.getElementById("animation-from");

button.addEventListener('click', function() {

  if (button.classList.contains("animated")) {
    button.classList.remove("animated");
    animationFrom.beginElement();
  } else {
    button.classList.add("animated");
    animationTo.beginElement();
  }

}, false);
```

```css
button svg {

  width: 40px;

  height: 40px;

  display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<button id="button">

  <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">

    <path id="play" d="m 2.5714275,0 0,24 9.4285695,-6.000001 0,-12 z m 9.4285695,5.999999 0,12 9.428576,-5.999998 0,0 z">

      <animate id="animation-to" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeName="d" dur="250ms" to="m 1.7142853,24 6.8571444,0 0,-24 -6.8571444,0 0,24 z M 15.428571,0 l 0,24 6.857144,0 0,-24 -6.857144,0 z" />

      <animate id="animation-from" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeName="d" dur="250ms" to="m 2.5714275,0 0,24 9.4285695,-6.000001 0,-12 z m 9.4285695,5.999999 0,12 9.428576,-5.999998 0,0 z" />

    </path>

  </svg>

</button>
```

Comment: It is animating for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/uumanojz/

Comment: If you take that fiddle and change `dur` to say `2500ms`, you can get a better sense of what is going on. It's animating, but quite jerkily, and so at 250ms it might look like no animation occurs.

Comment: If you want a smooth animation all the paths must have the same commands in the same order and the same number of co-ordinates in each sub-path.